# Trouble with VBA coding

Tags: excel, vba

- Row height is not adjusting correctly when pasting a section from one sheet to another using VBA.
- When clicking back and forth between radio buttons (using ActiveX), the section that is being pasted from another sheet sticks and does not clear the fields when going back and forth between buttons.

I have provided my very little code that has successfully pasted the section onto the main sheet.

```
Private Sub OptAdd_Click()
    Sheet2.UsedRange.Copy
    Sheet1.Range("C11").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub

Private Sub OptEdit_Click()
    Sheet3.UsedRange.Copy
    Sheet1.Range("C11").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Tried pasting some code such as this:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1) 
    .RowHeight = .RowHeight * 2 
End With
```

But it kept breaking my code causing errors.

Comment: My guess would be that the row height would be copied over if you copied the entire row. Since that's not the case here, perhaps a loop over the rows in the used range, assigning their row height to the relevant row on `Sheet1`.

Comment: Did you try pasting only values?

Comment: I have not. Can you give me an example of what the code may look like? I should have mentioned that this is only my 3rd day of using VBA so I am not entirely sure what you mean by pasting only values. Apologies!

Comment: This seemed to work for the widths: 

Sheet1.Range("B11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths

Any suggestions for the height?